# Why do my Woocommerce Subscriptions have failed token creations?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am a bit new to using WooCommerce and have purchased and installed WooCommerce Subscriptions.

Now that we have a few people sign up and purchase some of our products, we want to make sure everything is working right.

The initial purchase goes through, and the customer is charged, however when checking the order details on the subscription order page; the right column states the following error:

`The payment was processed, but the customer token creation failed. The subscription future payments may fail. Error message: There was an error while processing your request. Error Code: http_request_failed.  Error Message: A valid URL was not provided...`

If anyone has any idea why this may be happening, I would love some help here - I don't want our subscriptions having missed renewals when we are just starting to get rolling! :)

Please let me know what else I can provide to help outline this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What payment gateway was used to make the payment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.